# Different colors for points on a 2D plot based on value in 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, colors

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. The first two columns are my data. The third column only takes on binary values, 0 or 1. I'd like to plot the first two columns such that the points are color coded (in two colors) depending upon whether the corresponding value in the third column is 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you please show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3, 4],
                       B=[7.5, 7, 5, 4.5],
                       C=[0, 1, 1, 0]))

colors = {0: 'red', 1: 'aqua'}

plt.scatter(df.A, df.B, c=df.C.map(colors))
```

[image]

Comment: Another solution would be `df.plot.scatter('A','B', c=df.C.map(colors))`